# setScale in cocos2d for a specific time Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, jquery-animate, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to scale a sprite when the user gets an extra life and set it back to its normal value after 1 or 2 seconds.

I have this:

```
if (_score == 2)
{
    _life = _life + 1;
    string strLife = StringHelper::ToString(_life);
    _labelUpperLifeCounter->SetString(strLife);


    _labelUpperScoreLife->setScale(2.5f);

}
```

It's working but I don't know how to set it back to:

```
_labelUpperScoreLife->setScale(1.7f);
```

or even better to animate it 2-3 times like a pulse before it goes back to normal...

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the same are available in c++. This is how i could do that in obj-c

```
id scaleUp = [CCActionScaleTo actionWithDuration:.1f scale:2.5f];
id pause = [CCActionDelay actionWithDuration : 1.f];
id scaleBack = [CCActionScaleTo actionWithDuration:.1f scale:1.7f];
id seq = [CCActionSequence actions: scaleUp,pause,scaleBack,nil];
[_labelUpperScoreLive runAction:seq];
```

just the general idea :) the translation to c++ is your expertise. This will scale score, stall a bit, then return the scale to the initial state.

Comment: am I gonna declare scaleUp, pause, scaleBack and seq as floats in .h file? I can't get it to work. It shows me CCScaleBy and CCScaleTo only..

Comment: ok, you are using a 2.x or before version. Will work the same. State your version in any cocos2d version, this way you will have a better chance to get an API-correct answer ;) ... changing the API is cocos's favourite sport.

Comment: hmmm ... not too certain about c++ , id (in objective c) is just an object handle (generic).

Comment: cocos2dx 
The problem is that actionWithDuration doesn't work on my project... I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found another way because I've lost too much time...

I created a copy of the sprite and put it on top of the other. I've scaled it and fade it out...

```
_labelUpperScoreLife2->setVisible(true);
    _labelUpperScoreLife2->setScale(3.0f);
    _labelUpperScoreLife2->runAction(CCFadeOut::create(1));
```

It looks great!

Thank you for your answers!